# socket receive and send are very slow over TCP

Tags: android, linux, sockets, kernel

kernel_recvmsg with option MSG_WAITALL is taking long time to receive data. even tried default option with flag 0. Overall throughput is affected with kernel_recvmsg. TCP_NODELAY socket option also set. tried to change all kinds of recv and send buffer options, between client and server but overall throughput is not getting changed.

server: windows 10 PC
client: Android 7.1 linux version 4.4.63

testing in 5 ghz network...

Is there any options left over to try.

timers below added shows that more time is consumed in kernel_recvmsg. even perf tool calls shows more time is consumed in kenrel_recvmsg.

```
t_usb.rx_rcv_start = ktime_get();

while (total_rcvd < length && total_rcvd >= 0 &&
       !kthread_should_stop()) {

    kvec.iov_base = tcp_recv_buf+data_rcvd;
    kvec.iov_len = length-data_rcvd;
    data_rcvd = kernel_recvmsg(tcp_socket->socket, msg, &kvec,
        1, length - total_rcvd, MSG_WAITALL);


    if (data_rcvd > 0) {
        total_rcvd += data_rcvd;

    } else {
        vfree(tcp_recv_buf);
        return data_rcvd;
    }


}
t_usb.rx_start = t_usb.rx_rcv_end=ktime_get();
```

Comment: How slow is it (actual measurements)? What speed are you expecting, and on what basis? Is the connection going over WiFi, cable, bluetooth, or what? You might also try other Android devices and see how the speed is affected, as it can be highly dependent on hardware.

Comment: TCP is getting slow on large files. TCP_NODELAY and other options are mostly used for extra optimizations. post your code, perhaps there is some bugs...

Comment: @LarsH write is 6 MBPS and read is 8 MBPS, expected 20 MBPS for 5ghz network. testing with wifi router connected with windows PC and android device. sure i will check with android devices as client and server.

Comment: @nmnir its huge code base, trying to send USB packets over wireless. kernel driver will handle usb requests from usb stack and transmit over TCP sockets to server. bascially kernel sockets are used for communication..

Comment: So why do you think that you need to optimize the TCP?